# How to monitor multiple file through shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to monitor `Apache` and `Tomcat` logs through a shell script.

I could monitor single files through script. But How do I monitor multiple files through script?

I have written sample script for single files.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/root/logs_flow/apache_access_log
current=`date +%s`
last_modified=`stat -c "%Y" $file`

if [ $(($current-$last_modified)) -gt 180 ]; then
     mail -s  "$file is not updating proper" ramacn11@xx.xx.xxx
else
     mail -s  "$file is updating proper" ramacn11@xx.xxx.xxx
fi
```

I want to monitor the files `apache_error_log` and tomcat logs with same script.

Comment: How will the names of the all the files `apache_error_log` be suffix with `1`,`2` and so on? Can you use a glob pattern?

Comment: You can try `inotify` to monitor the whole directory.

Comment: @alijandro, triggering on changes isn't what he wants; what he's trying to do is trigger when certain files get older than some duration WITHOUT changes.

Comment: Look at something like `logstash`.

Comment: @hek2mgl - I think that given the level of scripting shown here, configuring (and maintaining) elasticsearch and logstash are probably a little out of scope. :-)

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution starting from what you have already would be to call your script with the file to monitor as argument:

```
script.sh /root/logs_flow/apache_access_log
```

Then inside you put

```
file=$1
```

Now you can put a bunch of these in cron

```
* * * * * script.sh /root/logs_flow/apache_access_log
* * * * * script.sh /some/other/file.log
```

You might want to expand your script a bit to check if the argument is passed and if it's a valid filename.

Comment: Hi Ramseyer, Thanks for response my question.  I am not able to add what you suggestion. because i am going to apply production environment. Can you suggestion all log files loop through single script. Is there any loop condition use for these log files. if you have anything, can you guide me for this request.

Answer (score 1):

You can list files that have or haven't been updated in a period of time using the `find` command, which will be more portable than processing the output of `stat`, which varies by operating system.

The following will output the names of specified logs that have a modification time more than 3 minutes ago:

```
find httpd.log tomcat.log -not -mtime -3m
```

Or, for more easier file list management, you could use a bash array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=(
    /root/logs_flow/apache_access_log
    /var/log/tomcat.log
    /var/log/www/apache-*.log     # This is an expanding glob.
)

find "${files[@]}" -not -mtime -3m
```

Files in the array will be listed if they are more than 3 minutes old.

Comment: The question was not tagged Linux, just wanted to mention that on Linux `inotifywatch` would be an option.

Comment: I wondered about `inotifywatch` as well, but it only seems to *report change events*; I couldn't see a way to have it tell us *when files reach a certain age*. Of course, I'm looking at the man page on a 6-year-old Ubuntu box. If you were to post a solution demonstrating how this works, I would +1 it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To read from multiple log files, at once.. One could do

```
tail -f /home/user/log_A -f /home/user/log_B |egrep -v "^$|="
```

**Note:** The `egrep -v "^$|="` part is to remove header lines and empty lines from the output of the tail command. You can remove that if you want to keep the headers.

Comment: It might not be clear that the `grep` is there to remove the header lines that `tail` produces when switching between the different inputs.  You might want to keep them, or to transform them (e.g. with `sed`) to suit your application, in which case, drop or replace the `egrep` command.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Done!